# why no sawtooth shape in memory usage statistics?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

Recently I made such experiment - new objects constantly spawned in a non-stop loop without saving any references of them, so they should get destroyed by garbage collector at nearest suitable moment. The only special thing is that objects are very big in terms of memory usage - one object holds array of 70 million elements. This is the code :

```
class Temp {
    private $data;

    function __construct() {
        $this->data = range(1,70000000);
    }
}

while (true) {
    new Temp();
}
```

I was very surprised that there is no any sawtooth typical behavior of garbage collector in memory usage graph. Here it is (70 million elements in array) :

[image]

**Question is - Where is [sawtooth](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/The_Generational_Garbage_Collector_Sawtooth) ?**

My best guess is that allocation and collection processes of objects starts to work concurrently or something else is going here.

**EDIT 1:**

When element count in array is decreased until 60 million - I get
sawtooth GC behavior as expected (60 million elements in array) :
[image]

**EDIT 2:**

In case if number of elements in array is *increased* (90 million elements in array) - I get a reversed sawtooth graph ! :
[image]

So seems that 70 million elements test is an edge-case between those two different shapes of sawtooth. But the reasons behind that are unclear to me.

Comment: Your experiment is not observing the garbage collector in any way. All your objects get destroyed when their reference count is 0, not because the garbage collector deems them as part of a cycle and therefore trash. You could adjust your script, by adding a new private member, say `$cycle`, and assigning a self reference in the constructor (`$this->cycle = $this`). I'm sure you'll see different results; but you might need to reduce the volume of your data to fit in the available memory.

Comment: When reference count is 0 object is just marked for removal from memory, but actual removal will be done by GC at time it finds most suitable. You can't destroy all unused objects in memory in the same time - thus cycles in GC and sawtooth behavior. And no - I don't need self-reference,- in that case object will live forever, so GC will never collect it, so there will be `out of memory` error soon in your suggested case

Comment: We clearly are talking about two different garbage collectors then. Good luck.